# How does a NN understand which class corresponds to which output node? and in turn how do we as people recognize what the probabilities correspond to?

Tags: python, deep-learning

Assuming we are trying to train an MNIST classifier, we would have 10 outputs (0-9). When the NN outputs the probabilities, how do we know which probability corresponds to which output node?

And even if we assume it's in order from the top node being 0 to the bottom most node being 9, how do we know this? and in turn how does the model know this? (i.e. Calculating the loss)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help].

Answer (score 1):

For a Neural network (NN) to know anything it first has to be trained. We do this by feeding it examples where we labeled the correct output ourselves. If we labeled that output 7 corresponds to a "3" then the network will slowly learn that. It makes more sense however to use output 1 for classifying class zero but that is all up to you.

Calculating the loss is usually done by evaluating a loss function. Often a logaritmic loss is used for multiclass classification.

Comment: Say you fed the model one hot encoded versions of each number from 0-9. How would that point to an output node exactly?

Comment: Are you using an off-the-shelf network or are you designing your own? This post discusses one hot encoding for classification and which loss functions to use: https://vigneshgig.medium.com/why-one-hot-encoder-is-important-in-classification-model-782c76604034